# Twitter button is creating multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I am using the Twitter **createShareButton** on my site (http://conn3cted.uk.tn/quote.html) but every time the 'New Quote' button is pressed it creates a new twitter button, leaving me with multiple buttons (e.g. if the 'New Quote' button is pressed 10 times, there will be 10 share buttons).

It was working fine a couple of days ago, so not sure what the hell has happened.

My JavaScript is below

```
// Random Quote Generator
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Set the default values for future AJAX requests
  $.ajaxSetup({
    // Prevent all future AJAX requests from being cached. 
    cache: false
  });
  // API URL
  var quoteURL = "http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1";
  // getQuote function, which accepts a data parameter. 
  var getQuote = function(data) {
    // Replace the html of the targeted element with the returned content field.
    $(".quoteContent").html(data[0].content);
    // Replace the html of the targeted element with the returned title field.
    $(".quoteTitle").html('Author: ' + data[0].title);
    newColor();

    twttr.ready(function() {
        // Use the pre-made createShareButton function
        twttr.widgets.createShareButton(
            // Do not share a URL
            " ",
            // Div where the share button should be inserted
            document.getElementById('tweetButton'),
            {
                // Define the tweet that will be used
                text: "'" + $(".quoteContent").text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"") + "'\n" +
                $(".quoteTitle").text(),
                // Set the size of the Twitter share button
                size: "large",
            }
        );
    });
  };

  var newColor = function() {
    var color = Please.make_color();
    $("body, button, .btn").css("background-color",color);  
    $("p, blockquote").css("color",color);
  };

  /*  
  * On every page load get JSON data from the URL, defined in the
  * 'url' variable, and then run the getQuote function 
  */
  $.getJSON(quoteURL, getQuote);
 //newColor();

 /*  
  * When the button is clicked load get JSON data from the   * URL,defined in the 'url' variable, and then run the
  * getQuote function.
  */
  $(".regenButton").click(function() {
    $.getJSON(quoteURL, getQuote);
  });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you create the twitter button in your `$.getJSON` success callback. So everytime a quote is loaded, a twitter button is created.

The best solution would be to create the button once, and update the share text everytime a quote is loaded. Which I can't find in the docs. So my best guess is to delete the previously one first:

```
var getQuote = function(data) {
  // Replace the html of the targeted element with the returned content field.
  $(".quoteContent").html(data[0].content);
  // Replace the html of the targeted element with the returned title field.
  $(".quoteTitle").html('Author: ' + data[0].title);
  newColor();

  // remove previous button
  $('.twitter-share-button').remove();

  // and create a new one
  twttr.ready(function() {
      // Use the pre-made createShareButton function
      twttr.widgets.createShareButton(
          // Do not share a URL
          " ",
          // Div where the share button should be inserted
          document.getElementById('tweetButton'),
          {
              // Define the tweet that will be used
              text: "'" + $(".quoteContent").text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"") + "'\n" +
              $(".quoteTitle").text(),
              // Set the size of the Twitter share button
              size: "large",
          }
      );
  });
};
```

Comment: Ah right ok! So it doesn't understand that it should only create one - I think I was confusing the HTML widget setup (that it only does it once) with the fact that this button shouldn't create multiple either.

But that does make sense - it is creating a new button as it has been told to do, just appending it to the specified `div`

I added that extra line in and all working now :-) thank you! As you can tell, I'm still learning. Sometimes I make stupid mistakes.

Comment: You're welcome, and it seems you understand the problem now! Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Your twitter share button code is inside the `getQuote` function - so each time `.regenButton` is clicked, `getQuote` is called, giving you another button.

Comment: Ah right ok! That makes sense. Where is the proper place to put this function? I tried adding it under `$.getJSON(quoteURL, getQuote);` but it doesn't pull down the quote that has been generated.

Comment: likely because your twitter button references `.quoteContent` which wont have any content until the quote button is pressed... you could either remove the previous twitter button, prior to creating it again, or look at the api to see if you can change its content after.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I was able to remove and recreate the button with the advice given by @Pimskie

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that comes across this post; I was looking into this a bit more and discovered a way to create the Twitter Share button without using the Twitter Widget.

First you need to create an A tag...

```
<!-- 
- href will create a link to the Twitter web intent composer
- target (_blank) will open the link in a new window
--> 
<a class="tweetButton" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Initial Text" 
                target="_blank">
<!-- Create a button for the link to interact with -->
   <button class="btn">
      Tweet
   </button>
</a>
```

And then setup jQuery to amend it for each new quote...

```
/*
* Amend the "href" attribute of the element with a "tweetButton" class
* (the "a" tag) to take the twitterURL Global Variable, plus the parameter 
* "text=" (which specifies what the tweet will say) and assign the value of:
*
* - the element with a class of "quoteContent", without the HTML tags 
* (.text()), removing all line breaks (.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")), 
* trims all the white space (.trim())
*
* - adds a line break (\n)
*
* - the element with a class of "quoteTitle", without the HTML tags
* (.text())
*
* Then URL encode the result (encodeURIComponent) to complete the amendment
*/
$(".tweetButton").attr("href", twitterURL + "text=" + encodeURIComponent("'" +
    $(".quoteContent").text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"").trim() +
    "'\n" + $(".quoteTitle").text()));
```